# How to get elements within a selected assembly

Tags: c#, revit-api, .net-4.8

Is there a way to get a collection of elements within a selected assembly? I'm using the "PickObjects" method to get the initial collection & out of that collection I want to pull what's within each of those assemblies separately. Out of each assembly I want to pull a collective sum of a specific parameter from each element. Hopefully that makes sense. Here is the code I used:

```
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class SetTpParameters : IExternalCommand
{
    public readonly string sharedFileLocation = "C:\\ProgramData\\Autodesk\\Revit\\Addins\\2021\\TpMechanical\\bin\\Debug";
    public readonly string sharedFileName = "TPMechanicalRevitParameters.txt";
    private static ExternalCommandData commandData;
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        var abc = "No Tp parameters  present";
        var def = "Add shared parameters to the model using the Add TPSPs button.";
        try
        {
            //Check for parameter file.
            var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var index = path.LastIndexOf("\\");
            var newPath = path.Substring(0, index);
            newPath += "\\TPMechanicalRevitParameters.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(sharedFileLocation, sharedFileName)))
            {
                TaskDialog.Show(abc, def);
                return Result.Cancelled;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        UIApplication uiApp = commandData.Application;
        UIDocument uiDoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document doc = uiDoc.Document;
        List<Element> e = (List<Element>)SelectElement(uiDoc, doc);
        foreach (Element element in e)
        {
            Parameter p = element.LookupParameter("TPFullFabricationServiceName");
            Parameter p2 = element.LookupParameter("TPSpoolWeight");
            Parameter p3 = element.LookupParameter("TPSpoolWeldInches");
            Parameter p4 = element.LookupParameter("TPTotalWeldInches");
            Parameter p5 = element.LookupParameter("TPLaborCode");
            Parameter p6 = element.LookupParameter("TP_WO_Number");
            Parameter p7 = element.LookupParameter("TPInvisibleParam");
            Parameter p8 = element.LookupParameter("TP_ITM_Weld_IN");
            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "SetParameters"))
            {
                t.Start();
                p3.Set("Test");
                p4.Set("Test");
                p5.Set("Test");
                p6.Set("Test");
                p7.Set("Test");
                try
                {
                    if (element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Pipe" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Tee" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Elbow")
                    {
                        p.Set(element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_SERVICE_NAME).AsString());
                    }
                    if (element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Pipe" &&
                        element.AssemblyInstanceId != null ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Tee" &&
                        element.AssemblyInstanceId != null ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Elbow" &&
                        element.AssemblyInstanceId != null)
                    {
                        Element assemblyInstanceID = element;
                         if (assemblyInstanceID.AssemblyInstanceId.IntegerValue.ToString() == null)
                         {
                            //p2.Set(element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PART_WEIGHT).AsDouble());
                            p2.Set(20);                                
                         }    
                    }
                    if (element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_INSTALL_TYPE).AsString().ToString() == "Weld" &&
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Pipe" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_INSTALL_TYPE).AsString().ToString() == "ButtWeld" &&
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Pipe" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_INSTALL_TYPE).AsString().ToString() == "SocketWeld" &&
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Pipe")
                    {
                        p8.Set(Convert.ToDouble(element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PART_WIDTH_IN).AsValueString()) * 2);
                    }
                    else if (element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_INSTALL_TYPE).AsString().ToString() == "Weld" &&
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Tee" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_INSTALL_TYPE).AsString().ToString() == "ButtWeld" &&
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Tee" ||
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_INSTALL_TYPE).AsString().ToString() == "SocketWeld" &&
                        element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT).AsString().ToString() == "Tee")
                    {
                        p8.Set(Convert.ToDouble(element.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PART_WIDTH_IN).AsValueString()) * 2);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    t.RollBack();
                    return Result.Cancelled;
                }
                t.Commit();
            }
        }
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
    public IList<Element> SelectElement(UIDocument uiDoc, Document doc)
    {
            List<Element> values = new List<Element>();
        try
        {
            IList<Reference> reference = uiDoc.Selection.PickObjects(ObjectType.Element);
            foreach (Reference r in reference)
            {
               Element el = doc.GetElement(r);
               Category bc = doc.GetElement(r).Category;
                if(el is FabricationPart)
                {
                    values.Add(el);
                }     
                //else if (bc.Id.IntegerValue is (int)BuiltInCategory.OST_Assemblies)
                //{
                //    values.Add(el);
                //}
            }              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TaskDialog td = new TaskDialog("Set Parameters");
            td.MainContent = "No Elements Have Been Selected";
            td.Show(); 
        }
        return values;
    }
```